# Возврат из функции объекта по ссылке

Tags: c++, указатели, ссылки

Изучаю С++ по книге С. Прата, пример взят из книги. Определен класс со следующей функцией:

```
const Stock & Stock::TopVal(const Stock & _st) const
{
    if (_st.total_val > total_val)
        return _st;
    else
        return *this;
}
```

Теперь в `main()` создаю массив объектов типа `Stock` и присваиваю указателю `top` значение одного из элементов массива:

```
for (int st = 1; st < STKS; st++)
{
    top = &top -> TopVal(stocks[st]);
}
```

Объясните, почему при присваивании указателю `top` значения из функции `TopVal` следует указывать знак ссылки, ведь из функции уже передается ссылка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из функции передается ссылка, но ссылка - это как бы псевдоним, а не адрес. Т.е. если у вас есть

```
int x;
int& r = x;
int* p = &x;
```

то `r` - обратите внимание, инициализируется `x`, а не адресом, как указатель. Как именно *внутренне* реализована ссылка - в данном случае не играет роли.

Вы используете `r` вместо `x` - например, в присваивании `r = 5;`. B точно так же вы получаете *адрес* через ссылку - `p = &x` тождественно `p = &r;`.

Непосредственно ссылка в указатель не преобразуется, и поэтому вам нужен оператор взятия адреса для возвращаемой ссылки.

Answer (score 3):

В этом предложении

```
top = &top -> TopVal(stocks[st]);
     ^^^
```

используется оператор взятия адреса `&`. В C++ многие символы перегружены и имеют несколько значений в зависимости от контекста. Так, например, символ `*` может означать бинарный оператор умножения, оператором разыменования указателя и использоваться в объявлениях для объявления указателя.

В свою очередь символ & может означать оператор взятия адреса, как в приведенной вами программе, ссылку при объявлении ссылок, а также бинарный битовый оператор AND.

Итак, в данном объявлении функции- члена класса

```
const Stock & Stock::TopVal(const Stock & _st) const
           ^^^                         ^^^ 
{
    if (_st.total_val > total_val)
        return _st;
    else
        return *this;
}
```

символ `&` используется для объявления ссылок. Функция возвращает ссылку на объект типа `const Stock`, а также объявляет в качестве параметра ссылку на объект такого эе типа `const Stock`.

А в этом предложении

```
top = &top -> TopVal(stocks[st]);
     ^^^
```

указателю `top`, который скорей всего объявлен как

```
const Stock *top;
```

присваивается адрес того объекта, ссылка на который возвращается из функции.

Чтобы было более понятно, то рассмотрите следующий пример

```
int x = 10;

int &r = x;

int *p = &x;

r = 20;

*p = 30;
```

В этом примере объявляется ссылка `r` на объект `x` и указатель `p`, который будет содержать адрес объекта `x`. Ссылку можно рассматривать как альтернативное имя объекта - как алиас объекта. То еть к области памяти, где расположен объект `x`, вы можете обращаться по исходному имени `x`, или используя имя `r`.

Answer (score -1):

В книге Стенли Б. Липпман, Жози Лажойе, Барбара Э. Му. Язык программирования C++. Базовый курс. Пятое издание. 2017 в главе 15 рассматривается иерархия классов Quote - Disc_quote - Bulk_quote.

У меня возникла необходимость передать в некоторую функцию ссылки объекты базового или производных классов и вернуть из этой функции также ссылки на эти объекты.

Приведенный на этой странице пример не срабатывает:

```
auto ref_return(Quote& ref_obj) { return ref_obj; };
// ... 
Bulk_quote  bulk_quote;

auto b_q = ref_return(bulk_quote);

// Возвращает не ссылку, а объект.

// У меня выстрелили вот такие конструкции:

//  Определение фунции, которая должна возвратить обычную ссылку:

auto ref_return(Quote& ref_obj) -> Quote& { return ref_obj; };

//  Вызов должен быть таким:

decltype(auto)  any_obj_ref = ref_return(bulk_quote);

// Такая же проблема была и с лямбда, и примерно так же она решилась:
//  Механизм возврата простой ссылки из лямда-функции:

//  Лямбда выражение должно быть таким:

auto ret_derived = [](Quote& any_quote_obj) -> Quote& {return any_quote_obj;};

Quote   any_quote_obj - объект базового класса

//  Вызов должен быть таким:

decltype(auto) bulk_quote_obj = ret_derived(bulk_quote);
```

Может быть, кому-нибудь окажется полезной эта информация.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/876952)